# Big Query Analytic Functions Improve Query Performance

Tags: google-bigquery

Pretty new to big query and hitting timeouts on a 100M point dataset.  I'm trying to find the points at which we reach a consistent series of values around 0 (stops) and points at which we consistently get above 0 (starts).

I saved the subquery that's being joined that determines the start file times to it's own dataset, but that didn't help. (seconds increments through multiple "files."

The part causing the problem is the initial aggregation of previous pts and next pts.

```
WITH test AS
 (SELECT 'A' as ACM, CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE) as file_date, CAST('10:10:10' AS TIME) as file_time , 0.0 as value, 0.1 as seconds
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.2 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 2000, 0.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 1000, 0.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -1000, 0.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -2000, 0.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.8 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.0 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 2000, 1.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -1000, 1.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -2000, 1.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.8
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 2000, 2.0
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 1000, 2.1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.2 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 20, 2.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.2 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 2000, 0.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 1000, 0.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -1000, 0.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -2000, 0.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.8 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.0 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 2000, 1.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -1000, 1.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -2000, 1.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.8
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 2000, 2.0
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 1000, 2.1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.2 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 20, 2.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.4 )
SELECT 
  acm,
  file_date,
  start_file_time,
  file_times,
  agg_sec as start_stop
FROM (
  SELECT 
    acm,
    file_date,
    start_file_time,
    file_times,
    ARRAY_AGG(kind) OVER w AS agg_kind, 
    ARRAY_AGG(seconds)  OVER w AS agg_sec
  FROM (
    SELECT
      acm,
      file_date,
      start_file_time,    
      ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(file_times) as x) AS file_times,
      seconds, 
      CASE 
      WHEN (ABS(prev_val) < 50 and ABS(next_val) >= 50 and next_avg >= 50 and prev_avg < 50 ) THEN 'start'
      WHEN (ABS(next_val) < 50 and ABS(prev_val) >= 50 and prev_avg >= 50 and next_avg < 50 ) THEN 'stop'
      END as kind,
      prev_val, next_val, prev_avg, next_avg
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        s.acm as acm,
        s.file_date as file_date,
        s.start_file_time as start_file_time,
        seconds, 
        value,
        ARRAY_AGG(s.file_time) OVER (PARTITION BY s.acm, s.file_date, s.start_file_time) as file_times,
        AVG(ABS(value)) OVER prev as prev_avg,
        NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER prev as prev_val,
        AVG(ABS(value)) OVER next as next_avg,
        NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER next as next_val
      FROM test v
      JOIN (
        SELECT 
          acm,
          file_date,
          file_time,
          TIME_SUB(file_time, INTERVAL CAST(FLOOR(MIN(seconds)) AS INT64) SECOND) as start_file_time
        FROM test
        GROUP BY acm, file_date, file_time
      ) s ON s.acm = v.acm AND s.file_date = v.file_date AND s.file_time = v.file_time
      WINDOW prev AS (PARTITION BY s.acm, s.file_date, s.start_file_time ORDER BY seconds ROWS 2 PRECEDING), next AS (PARTITION BY s.acm, s.file_date, s.start_file_time ORDER BY seconds ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
      )
    WHERE value = 0)
  WHERE kind IN ('start', 'stop')
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY acm, file_date, start_file_time ORDER BY seconds ROWS 1 PRECEDING))
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(agg_kind) = 2 AND agg_kind[ORDINAL(1)] = 'start' AND agg_kind[ORDINAL(2)] = 'stop'
;
```

Comment: please clarify - the example code in your post produces **correct result** but when applied to real data it times-out?

Answer (score 1):

Check if below version will make a difference
I tried to preserve your original code as much as possible

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH test AS
 (SELECT 'A' AS ACM, CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE) AS file_date, CAST('10:10:10' AS TIME) AS file_time , 0.0 AS value, 0.1 AS seconds
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.2 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 2000, 0.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 1000, 0.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -1000, 0.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -2000, 0.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.8 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.0 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 2000, 1.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -1000, 1.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -2000, 1.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.8
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 2000, 2.0
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 1000, 2.1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.2 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 20, 2.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.2 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 2000, 0.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 1000, 0.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -1000, 0.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', -2000, 0.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.8 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:10', 0, 0.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.0 #start
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 2000, 1.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.5
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -1000, 1.6
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', -2000, 1.7
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 0, 1.8
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:11', 1000, 1.9
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 2000, 2.0
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 1000, 2.1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.2 #stop
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 20, 2.3
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '2017-01-01', '10:10:12', 0, 2.4 
), temp1 AS (
  SELECT acm, file_date, value, seconds, 
   TIME_SUB(file_time, INTERVAL CAST(FLOOR(seconds) AS INT64) SECOND) AS start_file_time
  FROM test
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT 
    acm, file_date, start_file_time, seconds, 
    AVG(ABS(value)) OVER prev AS prev_avg,
    NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER prev AS prev_val,
    AVG(ABS(value)) OVER next AS next_avg,
    NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER next AS next_val
  FROM temp1 WINDOW 
    prev AS (PARTITION BY acm, file_date, start_file_time ORDER BY seconds ROWS 2 PRECEDING), 
    next AS (PARTITION BY acm, file_date, start_file_time ORDER BY seconds ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
), temp3 AS (
  SELECT
    acm, file_date, start_file_time, seconds, 
    CASE 
      WHEN (ABS(prev_val) < 50 AND ABS(next_val) >= 50 AND next_avg >= 50 AND prev_avg < 50 ) THEN 'start'
      WHEN (ABS(next_val) < 50 AND ABS(prev_val) >= 50 AND prev_avg >= 50 AND next_avg < 50 ) THEN 'stop'
    END AS kind
  FROM temp2
), temp4 AS (
  SELECT *, 
    COUNTIF(kind = 'start') OVER (PARTITION BY acm, file_date, start_file_time ORDER BY seconds) + 
    COUNTIF(kind = 'stop') OVER (PARTITION BY acm, file_date, start_file_time ORDER BY seconds ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
  FROM temp3
)
SELECT 
  acm, file_date, start_file_time, 
  MIN(seconds) AS start_seconds, 
  MAX(seconds) AS stop_seconds   
FROM temp4
GROUP BY acm, file_date, start_file_time, grp
HAVING MIN(kind) != MAX(kind)
-- ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this query gives you the results you are looking for and is capable of processing your dataset successfully:

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(file_data),
  ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(seconds, kind) FROM UNNEST(file_data) WHERE kind IS NOT NULL) file_data
FROM(
  SELECT
    ACM,
    file_date,
    start_file_time,
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT file_time FROM UNNEST(file_data)) file_times,
    ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(seconds, IF(value = 0, (CASE WHEN ABS(NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER(prev)) < 50 AND ABS(NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER(next)) >= 50 AND AVG(ABS(value)) OVER(next) >= 50 and AVG(ABS(value)) OVER(prev) < 50 THEN 'start'
                                                    WHEN ABS(NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER(next)) < 50 AND ABS(NTH_VALUE(value, 2) OVER(prev)) >= 50 AND AVG(ABS(value)) OVER(prev) >= 50 and AVG(ABS(value)) OVER(next) < 50 THEN 'stop' END), NULL) as kind)
          FROM UNNEST(file_data)  WINDOW prev AS (ORDER BY seconds ROWS 2 PRECEDING), next as(ORDER BY seconds ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)) file_data
  FROM(
    SELECT
      ACM,
      file_date,
      TIME_SUB(file_time, INTERVAL CAST(FLOOR(seconds) AS INT64) SECOND) AS start_file_time,
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(file_time, value, seconds)) file_data
    FROM test
    GROUP BY ACM, file_date, start_file_time
   )
 )
```

Its results is exactly what you described as "start" and "stop" in your `test` data.

A few notes to make:

- I avoided the expensive `JOIN` operation.
- Made use of ARRAYs and STRUCTs as much as possible which increases not only efficiency on storage but also increases query performance due processing of only desired data, i.e, no need to handle duplicated data.
- Just 2 `WINDOW` clauses each used inside of correspondent ARRAY structure which boosts performance. Notice this is possible because I aggregated everything in ARRAYs of STRUCTs so there's no need for more complex windowing clauses as data is already "sorted out".
- There's no data duplication in this query.
- Notice the results are in a slight different structure now, I'd recommend using this new one as it's more effective on data storage and further processing.

Let me know if this works for you.